# Disable ssh logins with weak passwords

Tags: ssh

Imagine an insane Debian server administrator, that added users with a weak password for a start and a hint, that they have to change it on the first login.

Now that he uses secure passwords only, is there a way to prompt every user with a weak password to change it to a more secure password with at least 12 characters, numbers, special-chars,... while not bothering users, that already have a secure password?

Comment: I doubt it. How do you determine that password is weak from the hash? That completely contradicts to the purpose of the hash (to be non reversible to the original input).

Comment: It could be determined at login, where the user enters the password

Comment: Or maybe use something like hydra to try all possible really simple passwords with only 5 letters yourself? see http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/25371/brute-force-an-ssh-login-that-has-only-a-4-letter-password

Answer (score 1):

Two step solution:

1. Don't allow users to create weak passwords.   You can partially do this with pam_unix.so with a line like in your pam configuration (presumably in `/etc/pam.d/common-password` or similar) (obscure and minlen=9 will help a little bit):

   ```
   password [success=1 default=ignore] pam_unix.so obscure minlen=9 sha512
   ```

   or install a more sophisticated password checker in PAM (like pam-cracklib that checks password strength, can check passwords against dictionaries, etc. whenever a user tries to change their password.).
2. If you previously allowed weak passwords, require all passwords to change on next login.  Look at `man shadow` to see to set password by setting date of last password change to `0`, granted you don't have to edit `/etc/shadow` directly -- you can do this with  `sudo chage -d 0 $USERNAME` (or use `sudo passwd -e $USERNAME`).  If you want to expire all passwords and everyone has a directory with their username in `/home` you can do:

   ```
   sudo su
   cd /home
   for USERNAME in *; do chage -d 0 $USERNAME ; done
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You need a [cracklib](https://github.com/cracklib/cracklib) and [PAM-cracklib](http://www.deer-run.com/~hal/sysadmin/pam_cracklib.html) to solve your case. The idea is that SSH will use PAM, and the password will be examined seamlessly and secure. Take a look at the last link I supplied - it contains a great tutorial, I have nothing to add to it

Answer (score 0):

No, he wouldn't be able to do that.

The password is only stored as a "hash" in /etc/shadow-. So the admin doesn't know what the passwords look like in the least.

So he can only prompt all users to change the password on next login and then verify that it is a good one.